# Twilio list-picker shows description after click

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api, content-editor

I'm using list-picker https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/twiliolist-picker to display lists in whatsapp.
And initially it's working like docs:

[image]

When the user clicks, the return on whatsapp is showing the title (item) + the description. Example:

[image]

The question is can i hide the description?
I didn't find anything about this in the documentation.

Thanks :)

I read all the documentation i found about the content editor and about the list-picker type